# Prove inequality trigonometric

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

For $\Delta ABC$. Prove that $$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C+\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B}+\frac{1}{\sin C}\ge 2\sqrt{3}+\frac{3}{2}$$

---

I have a solution but it is very long and easy to confuse. Help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ is convex in $(0,\pi)$. Hence
$$f(A)+f(B)+f(C)\geq 3f\left(\frac{A+B+C}{3}\right)=3f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=2\sqrt{3}+\frac{3}{2}.$$

P.S. Convexity:
$$f''(x)=-\cos(x)-\frac{1}{\sin(x)}+\frac{2}{(\sin(x))^3}$$
and for $x\in (0,\pi)$, $f''(x)>0$ iff $2>(\sin(x))^2(\sin(x)\cos(x)+1)$ which holds.

Comment: karamata's inequality ?

Comment: No, Jensen's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Comment: i think Jensen's inequality is a special case of karamata

Comment: You are right, Jensen is a particular case.

Comment: You are welcome!